# Geoserver Multiple ImageMosaic Rasters Issue

Tags: gis, geoserver, wms

I am attempting to develop a stack of OS Raster basemaps to be served by Geoserver as WMS.

I have set up separate image mosaic layers for the different map styles, and set appropriate Zoom Layering levels as styles for the layers. Each individual layer displays as required both in OL preview and within GIS applications.

If I combine these layers in a Layer Group however, the preview displays a blank image, although the Palette_Index values are displayed for both layers underneath the preview image.

Is it possible to accomplish what I am attempting to do in Geoserver, and serve the multiple raster layers as a single WMS?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

ADD:

- Geoserver version is 2.8.0
- Layer Group is simply compiled of the two imagemosaic Layers. The only change I have made from the default selections is to compute the bounds and apply an SLD style to each layer with a simple MaxScaleDenominator added which works for the layers when viewed individually.
- Also tried with the standard raster sld with no editing, and the issue persists

Comment: You should report the GeoServer version

Comment: It should work fine, can you add details of your layer group

Comment: Thanks for your responses, i've added a bit more detail, apologies if more is required, i'm quite new to this.